# Invalid conversion from runtime type MyClass.A to MyClass.B

Tags: apex

I have a class as follows.

```
public class MyClass{

   public virtual class A{}

   public class B extends A{}

   public A someMethod(){
      return new A();
   }

   public void myMethod(){
      B b1 = (B)someMethod();
   }
}
```

When executing `myMethod()`, i got this runtime error:

> Invalid conversion from runtime type MyClass.A to MyClass.B

I think as B is a child of A, instances of A can be cast to B.

Am I wrong? Why I got this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got the right idea, just a technicality in one direction.

I try and put a familiar analogy in my head for these things, eg:

- all Accounts are SObjects
- not all SObjects are Accounts.

You can get lucky at runtime if and only if you cast (Account) something that really is an Account.

---

If apex unilaterally permitted `A` to `B` casting at runtime, the `B` behaviours could be very ill defined.

His stuff that makes him a `B` (properties etc) could be *missing*. Exception thrown, surprise averted ;)

Comment: Thanks for your plain explanation. I am still doubt that when can we cast apex objects like `MyClass mc = (MyClass)JSON.deserialize('json string',MyClass.class);`? or Apex does not support casting between custom apex objects?

Comment: @JunKe interesting, what's the use case your'e trying to build?

Comment: I have a base class holding some common properties and methods, and some other classes extending the base class with specific properties or methods. There is a method returning the base class. I want to cast the return value to subtypes of the base class.

Comment: @JunKe maybe possible to use `abstract` base instead of `virtual` class, and then instantiate concrete children using `Type.forName().newInstance()` or such?

Comment: Thank you, I seem to understand it, the method declared to return a supertype, and the actual return value is constructed in subtype. In this case the casting will work, am I right?

Comment: @JunKe you got it -- then the caller would cast to the subtype before using it.