# Invalid conversion from runtime type

Tags: apex, class, inheritance

I basically have the same problem that was described here [Invalid conversion from runtime type MyClass.A to MyClass.B](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97916/invalid-conversion-from-runtime-type-myclass-a-to-myclass-b) but i'm unclear as to what the solution is

I have a virtual class A and classes B and C that both extend A. A has some fields, B and C do nothing have anything in them and are only used for the class name.

I have a method which return an A object. I then want to cast this object into a B and a C. Why am i getting this error?

example code

```
public virtual class A {
   //fields
}

public class B extends A {
   //nothing
}

public A someMethod(){
   return new A();
}

public void myMethod(){
   B b1 = (B) someMethod();
}
```

EDIT: apparently the solution is to create another helper method that will take a parent object as an argument. You create a child object, modify that object in your method (you can modfy both chil objects in the same way), return it as an object and then cast that object back into a child. Idk why but that worked.

Comment: Please **[edit]** this post to include your specific code.

Comment: @AdrianLarson done

Comment: I am afraid it might be a X-Y problem due to most recent edits (http://xyproblem.info/). Can you elaborate in details what is the scenario of usage of A, B and C and why do you want to cast A to B?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior for any Object Oriented Programming.

What you have currently returning from your method is the instance of the Parent Class, and thus it cannot be *cast* to an instance of Child Class.

```
public A someMethod(){
   return new A();
}
```

Only if you had your method something as below, it would have then worked.

```
public A someMethod(){
   return new B(); // returns instance of B
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do what i am trying to do then without creating two blocks of code for all the fields of class A?

Comment: You can return the parent type, but if you need to cast it to a child instance, you need to make sure that you create an instance of the child itself. While I am not completely sure what are you trying to achieve, you can always determine based on a parameter as which type of instance you need to create - parent or child.

Comment: basically i have two classes that have the same attributes but different class names and i want to write as little code as possible so i want a parent cass with all the details and child classes with different names and treat them similarly until the end where i make them into their child classes

Comment: Why do you need two classes then if all attributes are same? I would recommend you revisit your design here. There's no way that you can cast an instance of parent to child, that's simply not allowed.

Comment: it's because i have a model that on of my swagger classes converts to json so i need the class names to match the expected json format

Comment: @BenArnao you probably should have included that in your question (see the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). It's likely that there is a solution to your problem, but this approach may be incorrect. Consider asking a new question to ask your "X" problem, and leave the "Y" for the community to fill in.

Comment: @BenArnao As mentioned, unfortunately you will not be able to utilize what you have right now. As recommended by sfdcfox, it will be good to open a new question with what you are trying and look for recommendations on approach. The direct answer to this question is what I have provided and you cannot get away with it.

Comment: @jayant das i figured out what i need to do. I created a child object, passed it to a method that accepts a parent object, do all my logic in this method for both objects, return back an object and then recast it back to a child object. The main thing is i didn't want to have to rewrite any of the field assignments or logic for the different objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is class A

[image: Class A]

This is Class B and Class C they Both extends class A

[image: Class B and Class C]

Now when you try to put an instance of Class C in Class A, you can as C has A in it, so

But When you try other way round, Trying to Assign Instance of Class A in Class B. It will have blank hole for properties /method of B which you cannot call as you have instance of A .

In order to avoid that, compiler stops you from doing so.

Comment: what is the solution? class B and C don't have anything in them just the name is different

Comment: You know that, compiler doesnt. Its same in every language not just apex